# Method Overloading C++ -> Only one method called

Tags: c++, methods, overloading

I have this code, and the only method called is the 'double' one, why?

```
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int    abs(int i){ cout << i << endl; return 0; }; 
  long   abs(long l){ cout << l << endl; return 0; };
  double abs(double d){ cout << d << endl; return 0; }; 

  int main(){
   abs(-13.63); 
   abs(1); 
   abs(1000000000); //chama long abs(long l)
  }
```

Comment: rename method abs, it is clashing with inbuilt function abs()

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get your code to compile on [codepad](http://codepad.org/), I think your method was clashing with the core `abs` function, but this
adjusted version worked:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int    xabs(int i){ cout << "i:" << i << endl; return 0; }
long   xabs(long l){ cout << "l:" << l << endl; return 0; }
double xabs(double d){ cout << "d:" << d << endl; return 0; }

int main(){
 xabs(-13.63); 
 xabs(1); 
 xabs(1000000000); //chama long abs(long l)

 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
d:-13.63
i:1
i:1000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

A few minor edits to your code will help troubleshoot this a bit.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int    abs(int i)   { cout << "*1*  " << i << endl; return 0; }; 
long   abs(long l)  { cout << "*2*  " << l << endl; return 0; };
double abs(double d){ cout << "*3*  " << d << endl; return 0; }; 

int main(){
    abs(-13.63); 
    abs(1); 
    abs(1000000000); //chama long abs(long l)
    abs(1000000000L);
}
```

When I do this, I see that different versions are indeed being called, and that the number `1000000000` is not stored as a `long`, but as an `int`.  (At least on my machine here.)  I added the fourth call to force storage as a `long` and it seems to have worked.  This is what I get for output:

```
*3*  -13.63
*1*  1
*1*  1000000000
*2*  1000000000
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for the help. but not really.